# Get historical price data from dex on new chain

Tags: uniswap, pancakeswap

I need to get historical price data from a uniswap clone on a brand new blockchain. I cant use bitquery or similar api as it doesnt support this chain.
How could I go about it getting it directly from the uniswap clone, so I can use the data for tradingview candlestick charts?